# HTML/Javascript - Get rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ, skewX, skewZ from rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an HTML page with which I can dynamically generate a rectangle with 4 points. Each point can be set by holding the shift button and left-mouse click on the page. Now I want to calculate the rotationX, rotationY, RotationZ, skewX, and skewY of the created object. In the example below the coordinates(logged in console) are Point 1: X = 288, Y = 212. Point 2: X = 711, Y = 140. Point 3: X = 666, Y = 409. Point 4: X = 276, Y = 333

Can anyone explain to me if it's) possible to calculate these values? b) how to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Joost

[image]

```js
            var points = [];
            var lines = [];

            function createPoint(event) {
                if (event.shiftKey) {
                    if (points.length >= 4) {
                        resetPoints();
                    }

                    var point = document.createElement('div');
                    point.className = 'point';
                    point.style.left = (event.pageX - 2.5) + 'px';
                    point.style.top = (event.pageY - 2.5) + 'px';
                    document.body.appendChild(point);
                    points.push({ x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY });

                    if (points.length > 1) {
                        var startPoint = points[points.length - 2];
                        var endPoint = points[points.length - 1];

                        var line = document.createElement('div');
                        line.className = 'line';
                        line.style.left = startPoint.x + 'px';
                        line.style.top = startPoint.y + 'px';
                        line.style.width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, 2)) + 'px';
                        line.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
                        line.style.transform = 'rotate(' + Math.atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x) + 'rad)';
                        document.body.appendChild(line);
                        lines.push(line);
                    }

                    if (points.length === 4) {
                        var startPoint = points[points.length - 1];
                        var endPoint = points[0];

                        var line = document.createElement('div');
                        line.className = 'line';
                        line.style.left = startPoint.x + 'px';
                        line.style.top = startPoint.y + 'px';
                        line.style.width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, 2)) + 'px';
                        line.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
                        line.style.transform = 'rotate(' + Math.atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x) + 'rad)';
                        document.body.appendChild(line);
                        lines.push(line);

                        // Remove the event listener after creating the last line
                        document.removeEventListener('click', createPoint);

                        logPointCoordinates();
                        
                    }
                }
            }

            function logPointCoordinates() {
                console.log('Point Coordinates:');
                for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    console.log('Point ' + (i + 1) + ': X = ' + points[i].x + ', Y = ' + points[i].y);
                }
            }



            document.addEventListener('click', createPoint);
```

```css
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .point {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: red;
                width: 5px;
                height: 5px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            .line {
                position: absolute;
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you saying that once drawn it is the representation of a rectangular div which has been skewed/rotated and you want to find the CSS which would create the same look?